# Difference between `flutter run` and `flutter build` command?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter dev and I'd like to know the difference between `flutter run` command and `flutter build` command.

Thanks.

Comment: flutter Build just build your application, while flutter run builds and run into your connected device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `flutter build` command with one of following parameters: `apk`, `appbundle`, `ios`. This will produce an application to deploy or publish on AppStore, PlayStore, or some other distribution channels like Firebase.

The `flutter run` command will run your application on a connected device, or iOS simulator, or Android Emulator. You can also use `--verbose` command to get a detailed log while running the application.

Answer (score 1):

The command flutter run --release compiles to release mode. Your IDE supports this mode. Android Studio, for example, provides a Run > Run… menu option, as well as a triangular green run button icon on the project page. You can compile to release mode for a specific target with flutter build .

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes) doc explains it all

> By default, flutter run compiles to debug mode

> You can compile to release mode for a specific target with flutter
> build